# Android: drawing on large bitmap, 2 layers, best way?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-bitmap

im working on an app, that displays large(around 2000x2000px) bitmap in imageview. This image has to be that large since user can pinch to zoom it in order to see some details. App has to be able to draw circles on that image, and also to display image alone, without circles on it. I was using 2 layers but the problem is memory since 2k x 2k px is around 16mb of memory, and creating another bitmap(another 16mb), just to draw a few circles, is pointless in my opinion. Is there any way, that you can draw simple primitives on image, and also be able to display it without primitives(circles in my case)? 
Maybe somehow to store only modified pixels or sth?
Thanks!

Comment: Just as a memory optimization tip: take a look at BitmapRegionDecoder: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html. Using that component you can load just the currently visible clip of your large bitmap.

Comment: The problem with region decoding is that only visible area will be decoded, and on every zoom/drag app must decode regions again, so the UI won't be smooth.

Comment: That is not much of a trade-off given that you can save so much memory and make your app accessible to a wider range of Android devices with limited RAM. Users are used to that experience and even stock Android apps such as the image gallery uses that technique. I implemented a big image viewer a while ago using the region decoder. You need to come up with some optimization strategies such as keeping a low-res version of the image in memory that is always rendered as a replacement while zooming and panning. When the user stops touching the new region is loaded in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make another 2000x2000 `Bitmap` to draw those circles on. Just 'prerender' a circle, and then choose where you draw it.

I'm working under the assumption that you're drawing your 'big' image on a `Canvas`, since you have zooming features etc.

If you're not, you'll need to override your SurfaceView's `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method so that you can access the `SurfaceView Canvas`. I won't go into depth about that part since again I'm assuming you have it, but if not the implementation of that function would look like this:

```
//Overriding SurfaceView onDraw(Canvas canvas)
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas surfaceCanvas) {
  if(canvas == null) return; //No Canvas? No point in drawing then.
  surfaceCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
  //Draw your 'big' image on the SurfaceView Canvas
  insertYourBigImageDrawingFunctionHere(surfaceCanvas);
  //Now draw your circles at their correct positions...
  insertCircleDrawingFunctionHere(surfaceCanvas);
}
```

Now that you have access to the SurfaceView Canvas, you can choose precisely how things are drawn on it. Like circles for example...

I want to draw your attention to the multiple `Canvas`' being used below (surfaceCanvas vs. circleCanvas). I once thought that Canvas was a kind-of 'one Canvas for the whole app/activity' implementation, but it isn't. You are free to create `Canvas`' as you please. It is merely an instance of a tool to draw onto Bitmaps. This was a HUGE revelation for me, and gave me much more robust control over how Bitmaps are composed.

```
public void myCircleDrawingFunction(Canvas surfaceCanvas){
  //Make a new Bitmap for your circle
  Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
  tinyCircleBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(10,10, conf);
  //Make a new canvas using that Bitmap as the source...
  Canvas circleCanvas = new Canvas(cacheBmp);
  //Now, perform your drawing on the `Canvas`...
  Paint p = new Paint();
  circleCanvas.drawCircle(5, 5, 5, p);
  //Now the `Bitmap` has a circle on it, draw the `Bitmap` on the `SufaceView Canvas`
  surfaceCanvas.drawBitmap(tinyCircleBMP, 10, 10, p);
  //Replace the '10's in the above function with relevant coordinates.
}
```

Now obviously, your circles will zoom/pan differently to your 'big' image, since they are no longer being drawn at the same size/position of the 'big' image. You will need to consider how to translate the positions of each circle taking into account the current scale and position of the 'big' image.

For example, if your image is zoomed in to 200%, and a circle is supposed to appear 100px from the left of the big image, then you should multiply the pixel values to take into account the zoom, like this

(PsuedoCode):
`drawCircleAtX = Bitmap.left * BitmapZoomFactor`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the canvas API (if not I would suggest to)? if so you are just draw your image on the canvas and then the primitive shapes on top of the same canvas before display. This way you just keep a reference of the circles position in some basic data types and scale them as the user moves around and zooms, so you know where to draw them each frame.

Comment: well the problem is  loading image to canvas. Since canvas has to be drawn on some bitmap, you have to have one bitmap where it is drawn, and another bitmap, from where you assign your own image(bitmap). You can reduce this to not storing your own bitmap, but problem is that you will still have 2  bitmaps in memory for a second, which can cause oom error